# r - inner_join fails because of error finding by column in llply loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I believe I've got a scoping issue in my loop...I'm sure it's simple error...but I'm not sure how to fix. I am trying to loop through some data, and join dataframes using dplyr's inner_join. However, I can't seem to get the variable name right in the by argument. Here's a test case for what I am trying to do:

```
test_inner <- function() {
  df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2), val=c("a", "b"), stringsAsFactors=F)
  df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),val=c("c", "d"), stringsAsFactors=F)
  df3 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2),val=c("e", "f"), stringsAsFactors=F)
  l2 <- list(df2=df2, df3=df3)
  q1 <- list(df1=df1, df2=l2)
  q2 <- list(df1=df1, df2=l2)
  l1=list(q1,q2)
  vars = c("df2", "df3")
  llply(l1, function(x) { 
    llply(vars, function(y) {
      m <- inner_join(x$df1, x$df2[y], by="id", copy=T)
    })   
  })
}
```

I expect to be able to join df1 and df2 and create a newly merged data frame, but it fails with the following error:

```
Error: cannot join on columns 'id' x 'id': index out of bounds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `[` instead of `[[` to extract element `y` of `x$df2`. That of course returns a list with one element instead of the element (i.e. the data.frame). Just use the correct extraction function.

Comment: Argh! Thanks, @shadow24 , that's it. If you add answer I will give you credit.